# flutter - How can text on stack not up when keyboard appears?

Tags: forms, layout, dart, flutter

Im making an authentication screen where there are `Text` widgets and `TextField` wrapped in `Stack`.

However, when writing in the `Textfield`, following the activation code (`Text`) below is pulled up when the keyboard appears;

[image: see image]

How to keep the following code position constant at the bottom and when the keyboard appears it is overwritten?

**Any answell will appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap You `Stack` widget inside a `listview`, this way the keyboard won't have any effect on its position.

Comment: OMG The bestttt